# Initialize variable using a temporary

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to C++. Say, I have a toy class as follows:

```cpp
class Date {
public:
    Date()
    {
        cout << "default constructor\n";
    }
    Date(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        cout << "constructor\n";
    }

    Date(const Date& d)
    {
        cout << "copy constructor\n";
    }

    Date& operator=(const Date& d)
    {
        cout << "copy assignment\n";
        return *this;
    }

};
```

If I initialize a `Date` object using `Date d = Date{ 2012,12,31 };` I would expect an unnamed temporary object of type `Date` first to be constructed according to the right-hand side, then, the value of the temporary to be copied into `d` on the left-hand side. If so, I expect my program to print out `constructor` and then `copy constructor`. However, the result implies that the copy constructor is not used as it only prints `constructor`:

```cpp
Date d = Date{ 2012,12,31 };  // constructor
```

On the other hand, copy assignment and copy construction work as expected:

```cpp
Date d1;  // default constructor
d1 = Date{ 2012,12,31 };  // constructor
                         // copy assignment
Date d2 = d1;  // copy constructor
```

My current guesses for `Date d = Date{ 2012,12,31 };`:

1. Compiler treats `Date d = Date{ 2012,12,31 };` as `Date{ 2012,12,31 };` i.e. compiler kind of "optimizes" `Date d =` away and generates object code for `Date{ 2012,12,31 };`
2. First, the unnamed temporary is constructed according to `Date{ 2012,12,31 };`, then, the system somehow attaches the name `d` to that temporary and somehow turns it in to a "normal" object.

May I ask which one of my guesses is correct?

Or if they are both wrong, could anyone tell me why code like `Date d = Date{ 2012,12,31 };` does not call copy constructor? (if it is an optimization, why wouldn't `d1 = Date{ 2012,12,31 };` just discard the old `d1`, create the new object and name it `d1`?)

---

**A follow-up question**:

In my current understanding, what is returned by a function is a temporary which holds the return value.

Let `day()` be a function call of a function whose return type is `Date`. Consider:

```cpp
Date d3 = day();
```

Now, if my second guess is correct, then, is it possible that the object we get from this line the temporary returned by `day()` which is attached with the name `d3`? If so, is it possible that `d3` might be unintentionally destroyed after this line as it was a temporary? (I know that if a reference is attached to a temporary, the lifetime of that temporary will be extended to meet the lifetime of the reference, but I think here we are in a different situation)

More to the point, may I ask how does C++ ensure that `Date d3 = day();` copies the value from `day()` to `d3`?

Many thanks!

Comment: direct initialization is a well defined term. Not sure if you refer to that or you just used it because you thought it fits to describe the line of code. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: see also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

Comment: *may I ask how does C++ ensure that Date d3 = day(); copies the value from day() to d3?* -- As long as the code works correctly, that's all that matters.  See the [as-if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule.

Comment: Note that from C++17, copy elision is guaranteed, but you can use c++11 and disable copy elision to get the output that you expected. Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/vhx71rbzj

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Date d = Date{ 2012,12,31 };
> ```

Pre-C++17: As specified for the abstract machine, a temporary object is created and the variable is copy-initialised. But this copy is allowed to be optimised and instead the variable is initialised directly without the temporary object having existed in the first place. This is called copy elision.

Post-C++17: The initialiser for the prvalue is used to initialise the variable. There is no temporary object and no optimisation is required. This is same as the optimised pre-C++17 behaviour except it is guaranteed rather than only allowed.